# 2009 Dodge grand Caravan SXT 4.0 V6. I need to know what I have to do to bypass. The AC compressor is a shorter belt capable of doing it

Tags: dodge, serpentine-belt, grand-caravan

2009Dodge grand Caravan, SXT`

need to bypass the AC compressor pulley well shorter belt work it’s a 4.0 L motor
`